# Xcode: Tests Failed without any errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm currently working on a huge project with many frameworks. I used Carthage to install them.
The main issue is that I can't run any tests. It just says that build succeeded but tests failed. No green nor red things appear.

I've tried to clean derived data, clean build folder, reinstalled Carthage but nothing worked.

One more thing is that the log keeps saying Bundle "BundleName" is damaged or missing for almost every package. I used to have 2 Xcode versions so I had the wrong Xcode-select path but it didn't work either after I changed it.

Any clues?

Comment: Just to be sure, you do have at least a single dummy test in there, right? :)

Comment: @IcarusTyler Yeah sure

Comment: You need to manually add Carthage frameworks to your unit tests